# Full SQL Statement History

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing a problem on a particular table in my database. The rows are being deleted without any reason (I have some procedures and triggers that modify the information inside the table but they are already tested).
So I need to see which DML statements are executed against the table.
I have already tried some methods, like using this query:

```
select SQL_FULLTEXT, FIRST_LOAD_TIME, ROWS_PROCESSED, PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME from v$sql;
```

filtering by the name of my table, or tried the SQL log.

Both methods don't show me the complete history of SQL executed (for example I can't see the statements executed by the procedures).

Can anyone give me some advice of where I can see ALL the DML executed in the database?

Comment: What do you mean with "registers"?

Comment: I mean the rows

Comment: crazy thought - are you sure your data is being COMMITTED within your session transaction? they might have never been 'saved' to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You're using a few terms that aren't defined within the context of Oracle Database, both 'sentence' and 'register.'

However.

If you want to see WHO is touching your data in a bad place, causing it to be deleted or changed, then you have 2 options.

Immediately, check your REDO logs. We have a package, dbms_logmnr, that will allow you to see what activity has been logged. Assuming that your tables weren't created with NOLOGGING clause, those UPDATEs and DELETEs should be recorded.

Tim has a nice article on this feature [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/logminer).

The better solution going forward is [AUDITING](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tdpsg/auditing-database-activity.html). You'll want to enable auditing in the database to record WHO is doing WHAT to your tables/data. This is included as part of the Enterprise Edition of the database. There is a performance hit, the more you decide to record, the more resources it will require. But it will probably be worth paying that price. And of course you'll have to manage the space required to maintain those logs.

Now, as to 'SQL Developer' and it's HISTORY feature. It ONLY records what you are executing in a SQL Worksheet. It won't see what others are doing. It can't help you here - unless this is a 1-man database, and you're only making changes with SQL Developer. Even then, it wouldn't be reliable as it has a limit, and only records changes done via the Worksheet.

Comment: Enabling auditing requires the enterprise edition if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name aye, yes, thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very helpful.